# Sorting a NSTableView column with IPv4 addresses

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, ipv4, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort an NSTableView column with IPv4 addresses using an SortDescriptor. This I have so far:

```
NSArray *devicesSortDescriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ip" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id ipstring1, id ipstring2) {
        const char * ipch1 = [ipstring1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        const char * ipch2 = [ipstring2 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        struct in_addr ip1, ip2;

        inet_aton(ipch1, &ip1);
        inet_aton(ipch2, &ip2);

        if (ip1.s_addr > ip2.s_addr)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        else if (ip1.s_addr == ip2.s_addr)
            return NSOrderedSame;
        else
            return NSOrderedAscending;
    }]];
```

And this is the result:

[image: strange sorted IPv4s]

What am I doing wrong? I mean if ip1.s_addr > ip2.s_addr then its of cause NSOrderedDescending.. o_O

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out, that all you need is a numeric comparator:

**Objective-C:**

```
comparator:^(NSString *a, NSString *b) {
        return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
    }
```

**Swift:**

```
comparator: {
        (a, b) -> NSComparisonResult in

        let result = a.compare(b as! String, options: NSStringCompareOptions.NumericSearch)
        return result
    }
```

:)